# Rails 4: User Authentication - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I've setup a moreless simple social user authentification on top of devise using *Google, Linkedin, Dropbox* and *Github*.
The *Dropbox* authentication does not work, instead it gives that error on the callback URL
(http://localhost:3000/users/auth/dropbox/callback):

```
NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#dropbox
undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
```

*Issue:* User Model (line 8)
**My Code:**

*Callbacks Controller:*

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

    def all
        user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'], current_user)
        if user.persisted?
            sign_in user
            flash[:notice] = t('devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', :kind => User::SOCIALS[params[:action].to_sym])
            if user.sign_in_count == 1
                redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
            else
                redirect_to root_path
            end
        else
            session['devise.user_attributes'] = user.attributes
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end

    User::SOCIALS.each do |k, _|
        alias_method k, :all
    end

end
```

*User Model:*

```
# omniauth Gem
def self.from_omniauth(auth, current_user)
    authorization = Authorization.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid.to_s,
                                        :token => auth.credentials.token,
                                        :secret => auth.credentials.secret).first_or_initialize
    authorization.profile_page = auth.info.urls.first.last unless authorization.persisted?
    if authorization.user.blank?
        user = current_user.nil? ? User.where('email = ?', auth['info']['email']).first : current_user
        if user.blank?
            user = User.new
            user.skip_confirmation!
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
            user.fetch_details(auth)
            user.save
        end
        authorization.user = user
        authorization.save
    end
    authorization.user
end

def fetch_details(auth)
    self.email = auth.info.email
    self.username = auth.info.name
    self.avatar = URI.parse(auth.info.image)
end
```

I appreciate each help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly:
    The `undefined method "first" for nil::NilClass` is happening because  you are attempting to call the method `first` on an empty, or nil object.

It's probably in your user model where you are attempting to find a User from a current_user.

`if authorization.user.blank?
    user = current_user.nil? ? User.where('email = ?', auth['info']['email']).first : current_user
    #This will cause the error that you are describing if both the current_user is nil and there is no User whose email is auth['info']['email']`

Now, There's a few things wrong with this. If they are attempting to log in to your application, then current_user at this stage should be unset.

You could try changing this to

`user = User.where(email: auth['info']['email']).first_or_create`

Which will create a new instance of User, if one does not exist with the email provided in the Authorization.
Then you can continue with

`user.persisted?`
which returns true for an existing user, and false for a new instance of User

Comment: I think the the problem is in line 5 of the User model, because the error persisted after I incorporated your suggestions. It seems like for Dropbox it somehow cannot find a url.

Comment: So, the same principle applies. You are calling `.first` on `auth.info.urls` which means it's either empty or doesn't exist. do debug use pry or byebug to stop your program right before this line and check what the auth is actually returning, then shape your code accordingly.